# AngularJS not parsing template parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a select element as a template in a custom directive. It takes an array as a parameter, but it is not parsed.

```
directive('myFilteringselectelement', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<span>{{filters[0][1]}}{{filters[0]}}{{selectfiltercount}}{{filters[selectfiltercount]}}</span><select send-message-select ng-model="myfilter" ng-options="filter.name for filter in {{filters[selectfiltercount]}}>"</select>'
    }   
}).
```

Two dimensional array "filters" is defined as:

```
$scope.filters = [  [{name: 'iron'}, {name: 'tin'}, {name: 'copper'}],
                    [{name: 'type1'}, {name: 'type2'}, {name: 'type3'}],
                    [{name: 'road1'}, {name: 'road2'}, {name: 'road3'}],
                    [{name: 'gwa1'}, {name: 'gwa2'}, {name: 'gwa3'}],
                    [{name: 'area1'}, {name: 'area2'}, {name: 'area3'}]
];
```

The span in the template is for testing purposes and it works well:

```
{{filters[0][1]}}
{{filters[0]}}
{{selectfiltercount}}
{{filters[selectfiltercount]}}
```

But the select element isn't working well:

```
<select send-message-select ng-model="myfilter" ng-options="filter.name for filter in {{filters[selectfiltercount]}}>"</select>
```

It is explained in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select that array parameter in ngOptions will work. It is working when I use the filters array with one dimension e.g.:

```
$scope.filters = [{name: 'iron'}, {name: 'tin'}, {name: 'copper'}];
```

But I want use 2 dimensional array in order to use multiple select directives. When there are multiple select directives, all select options become same with one dimensional array (latest assignment...)

What could be the reason that it is not parsed? Any ideas?

Cheers,
Alp

Here is the error log thrown from chrome:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=%5B%7B%22name%22%3ANaNron%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22tin%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%copper%22%7D%5D%3E&p4=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%iron%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22tin%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%copper%22%7D%5D%3E
    at Error (native)
    at http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at hb.throwError (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:190:254)
    at hb.primary (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:190:6)
    at hb.unary (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:197:82)
    at hb.multiplicative (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:196:324)
    at hb.additive (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:196:182)
    at hb.relational (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:196:125)
    at hb.equality (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:195:418)
    at hb.logicalAND (http://1x7.0.0.1:8000/app/components/javascripts/angular.min.js:195:294) angular.min.js:103
    (anonymous function) angular.min.js:103
    (anonymous function) angular.min.js:76
    $ angular.min.js:70
    v angular.min.js:59
    g angular.min.js:52
    v angular.min.js:59
    g angular.min.js:52
    (anonymous function) angular.min.js:51
    (anonymous function) filter.js:96
    n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
    r.handle jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-options does not take interpolation. Also ending quotes seems to be incorrect. Can you try

`ng-options="filter.name for filter in filters[selectfiltercount]"`